# Canadian GST/Accounting Question for iPhone App Developers

Tags: iphone, app-store

I realize this isn't exactly a coding question, but it's the best place I can think of to reach fellow iPhone developers. I apologize if this causes any issues...

We are a Canadian corporation that files GST and filled out the Canadian GST/HST Form 506 which allows apple to collect and remit GST on our behalf. We recently received a "GST Tax Advice" document that outlines the revenue collected on our behalf, commission charged (including GST) and a breakdown of the commission charged.

My question is: do we need to include the GST on the total revenue collected when we file our quarterly GST Return? And then do we apply the GST that was charged on Apple's commission to our Input Tax Credits (ITC)?

There seems to be very little information on this and it is all quite confusing. Apple, of course, was no help either =/ Hopefully someone else has been in the same boat as us?

Cheers

Comment: This is not the appropriate place for this question, but I would recommend you ask on the iPhoneSB mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesb .  Someone there might be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I joined the mailing list and will solicit help from there.

Answer (score -1):

This would be best answered by your accountant or by asking at a government office.

Here are a couple of links that may help:
http://www.wikihow.com/Complete-a-Canadian-GST-Return

http://www.unisa.edu.au/Fin/Tax/gst/faqsGST.asp